# FutureBuilder always return Instance of Future

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to display a custom message when user logs or when log fail.
My post api call returns nothing, so I wanted to base on response status code to know if log went well or not.

I did something like in my api :

```
  Future<Response> login(String email, String password) async {
     final http.Response response = await http.post(
     baseUrl + 'auth/login',
     headers: headers,
     body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic> {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    }),
);
return response.statusCode == 200 ? Response(statusCode: 200) : Response(message: "Failed to login");}

class Response {
 final String message;
 final int statusCode;

 Response({this.message, this.statusCode});

 factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Response(
    message: json["message"],
 );}}
```

And I call this method inside a FutureBuilder to display the message:

```
       FutureBuilder(
         future: lap.login(emailController.text, passwordController.text),
         builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Response> snapshot) {

           if(snapshot.hasData)
             print(snapshot.data.statusCode);
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
         },);
```

In my print method, I print nothing I don't understand why it doesn't display status code I return in my api method.

Could someone know why ?

Comment: That is not possible as `statusCode` does not return a `Future`. Essentially, the `print` statement you are describing *cannot* come from the code you posted.

Comment: yes sorry, I edit my post, I was printed the method below. Actually, I don't print anything....

Comment: It would makes sense if your network call is actually failing, and the `Response(message: "Failed to login")` is being returned instead? Try printing `data.message` instead?

Comment: Whatever I print inside my builder prints nothing. I precise it's on a RaisedButton click, but I guess it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally did the job with a .then(). 
Still don't understand why the first way didn't do it but after all, it works.

```
 onPressed: () {
   if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      lap.login(emailController.text, passwordController.text)
      .then((responseMessage) => Scaffold
      .of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(responseMessage.message))));
   }
},
```